# How do I fix this error message "Initialization error (Eslint). Unexpected Identifier"?

Tags: webstorm, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have *Eslint* and *JSCS* setup to reformat some code base with *airbnb js style guide* in *WebStorm*. I have been using this setup effectively for the past 2 days, but all of a sudden, WebStorm started throwing this error...

> Problem with ESLint reformatting:index.js: Initialization error (ESLint). Unexpected identifier

[image]

I thought maybe I had some error in my *.eslintrc* but then I had used the same config to successfully refactor about 150 files before this sudden error. 
Prior to this, the *JSCS* compiler was occasionally throwing "less than a minute timeout" exceptions, but then I would fix this with closing and reopening the file. The *eslint* though seems not to be falling for this trick.

**This is my `.eslintrc` config**

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "document": false
  },
  "rules": {
    "validateIndentation": 4,
    "func-names": [
      "error",
      "never"
    ],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      1,
      {
        "extensions": [
          ".js",
          ".jsx"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": [
      2,
      {
        "components": [
          "Label"
        ],
        "required": {
          "some": [
            "nesting",
            "id"
          ]
        },
        "allowChildren": false
      }
    ],
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [
      "error",
      {
        "components": [
          "Link"
        ],
        "specialLink": [
          "to",
          "hrefLeft",
          "hrefRight"
        ],
        "aspects": [
          "noHref",
          "invalidHref",
          "preferButton"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Some part of `package.json`**

```
{
    "eslint": "^4.14.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.40.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app",
      "flow"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

Can some one throw me some pointers on how I can go about fixing this. I suspect it might be more of a WebStorm error than Eslint.

PS: Forgive me if this question might be better suited at *superuser*. I just thought it's most likely someone here might have faced the same issue.

Comment: @lena, `Problem with ESLint reformatting:index.js: Initialization error (ESLint). Unexpected identifier` is the same message that appears on clicking show ballon link. It just re formats the same message in a better looking ballon tooltip box.

Comment: no idea:( please share a sample project that can be used to recreate the issue, plus your idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)

Comment: @lena,  was not able to recreate the issue with a fresh project the were passing the linting with the same setup. However testing the eslint on non `js` files produced a much more detailed error pointing to eslinting in lodash.   `yarn upgrade` helped

Comment: I had a simular problem, but mine got solved by updating node from version 8 to 14. Simplest way was just to download a new version of node from nodejs.org and run the installer.

Comment: @Rikard's fix works. If you need to do this inside WebStorm, open Preferences, go to Language and Frameworks->Node.js and NPM->Node interpreter. Mine defaulted to the first version of Node I'd installed, but I also use nvm. I fixed my issue by pointing to a newer version of Node from within nvm.

Comment: As corinna000 already hinted, this also applies to other JetBrains products such as RubyMine. (Tested on `2022.3`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by a `yarn upgrade`

---

My attempts at recreating the issue with a fresh project failed, with the same configs, both `eslint` and `jscs` were running successfully.

However on using the WebStorm context menu command *`Apply ESlint Code Style Rules`* on non `js` files(tested on .eslintrc itself), i got a much more detailed error.

> Error on attempt to find parent and base ESLint configuration files of '.eslintrc': `[projectpath]`\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:386 '\u0149': ''n', '\u017f': 's',

I double checked lodash package node_modules and package.json, tripple checked the settings configs(Eslint & JSCS) and was sure I had identical setup to the test projects that were linting without errors.

Running **`yarn upgrade lodash`** saved my hair. Since I was already running the latest lodash, I think yarn's Resolving and Rebuilding the packages did the trick.

Hope someone might find this helpful somewhere along the line.

Comment: `npm upgrade` saved me

Comment: I get the same error after adding a newer package. `yarn upgrade eslint` fixed my PyCharm issue.

Answer (score 19):

i use this pattern for my eslint configuraion in phpstorm and error has gone now,

```
{**/*,*}.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,html,vue},{!node_modules/*}
```

Comment: Good point using **,{!node_modules/*}**, It solved the error for me

Comment: I agree with A-Palgy. You set this pattern in the ESLint settings at "Run for files". It fixed [`ESLint: Inizielization error (ESLint). Unexpected token ...` for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTOoX.png). These settings are directly linked at the end of this error message line.